# Why ajax.stop works not only one time

Tags: jquery

I want, that a ajax.stop function works only for one time - at the first pageload, after that, I don't need this function. For that I have tried it with this code.

```
if(init===false)
      {     
            console.log('1) loadpage start');
            load_page(<?php echo $page->id;?>);
            //Wait till the page is recieved, than go on
            $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                  console.log('2) load page -> ajaxStopp init:'+init);
                  setup_elements();
            });                       
            init=true;
      }
```

I wondering why the ajaxstop function will work again if I do later another ajaxcall. At this I get the `"2)"` message from the console instead I see that the variable "Init" is true.

Maybe I understand the way which `ajax.stop` works wrong?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/  *Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event.*

Comment: You are creating an event handler for the ajaxStop event.  It doesn't matter if you set the init to true or false after that point.  The event handler will still exist and execute for the events it receives.  If you do not want that to happen, you will need to remove the event handler after it executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**5 years after update** (Thanks to Taplar and Dexter):

```
$(document).one('ajaxStop', function() {
  console.log('2) load page -> ajaxStop');
    setup_elements();
});
```

The [.one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method registers an event handler to be executed only once.
[ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) is the event used above.

---

**Previous answer**

> Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed.
> [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

So what you wish to do probably is this:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  if(init===false){
    console.log('2) load page -> ajaxStopp init:'+init);
    setup_elements();
    init=true;
  }
});
```

So you just misplaced your `if` condition.

Now `ajaxStop()` will still execute every time an ajax resquest has completed... But will do nothing, except on page load.

Comment: Or potentially change to use `one()` so the event binding unregisters itself after it is done.  Or, don't use ajaxStop at all, and add a then() to whatever ajax call the load is doing.